# Selenium - Message: no such element: Unable to locate element

Tags: python, selenium, xpath, css-selectors, nosuchelementexception

Code trials:

```
img_source = driver.find_element_by_css_selector('#root > div > div > div > div.MainFrameContainer > div > div > div > div > div > div > div.reader-area > div.reader-pages-container > div:nth-child(4) > img.f.e').get_attribute('src')

thumbs = driver.find_element_by_css_selector('div.thumbnail-storage')
driver.execute_script('arguments[0].scrollBy(arguments[0].scrollWidth, 0)', thumbs)
sleep(1)
pages = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector('#root > div > div > div > div.MainFrameContainer > div > div > div > div > div > div > div.reader-scrubber-container > div > div:nth-child(1) > h1 > div.pages-counter > span:nth-child(3)')
```

Html for image url:

```
<img crossorigin="anonymous" src="blob:https://1.mysite/7e50ba18-3f0f-4b8d-acff-5684d3d551bc" class="f e" style="width: 2000px; height: 2697px;">
```

When run bot tell me error:

```
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"css selector","selector":"#root > div > div > div > div.MainFrameContainer > div > div > div > div > div > div > div.reader-area > div.reader-pages-container > div:nth-child(4) > img.f.o"}
```

Comment: Is it under shadow-root ?

Comment: yes. no help?? my problem for src and images

Answer (score 1):

As per the HTML:

```
<img crossorigin="anonymous" src="blob:https://1.mysite/7e50ba18-3f0f-4b8d-acff-5684d3d551bc" class="f e" style="width: 2000px; height: 2697px;">
```

To extract the value of the *src* attribute you can use either of the following [*locator strategies*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver):

- Using *css_selector*:

  ```
  print(driver.find_element_by_css_selector("img[crossorigin='anonymous'][src^='blob']").get_attribute("src"))
  ```
- Using *xpath*:

  ```
  print(driver.find_element_by_xpath("//img[@crossorigin='anonymous' and starts-with(@src, 'blob')']").get_attribute("src"))
  ```

---

Ideally you need to induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59130336/7429447) for the [*visibility_of_element_located()*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50474905/7429447) and you can use either of the following [*locator strategies*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48056120/7429447):

- Using *CSS_SELECTOR*:

  ```
  print(WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "img[crossorigin='anonymous'][src^='blob']"))).get_attribute("src"))
  ```
- Using *XPATH*:

  ```
  print(WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//img[@crossorigin='anonymous' and starts-with(@src, 'blob')']"))).get_attribute("src"))
  ```
- **Note** : You have to add the following imports :

  ```
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  ```